# Table of content abnormally closing after using showAttributeTable (Processing plugin)

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have recently developed a ***Processing* plugin** for **QGIS 3.16**, which aims to analyze biodiversity data from a specific PostgreSQL database (https://github.com/lpoaura/PluginQGis-LPOData). It is used by several employees in our company.

For each algorithm, a spatial or non-spatial layer is created and its table of content is opened at the end of the code execution, with the following command:

```
iface.showAttributeTable(output_layer)
iface.setActiveLayer(output_layer)
```

Depending on people feedback, **two problems can be faced** here :

- either the table of content **opens up and closes immediately** without having displayed the content;
- or the table of content **opens up and gets frozen** (that means that you can’t even scroll or select an action from the window). You need to close it and open again to fix the problem.

I can’t find any error message on QGIS desktop after this, so I don’t know what’s happening. Apparently this issue has already been raised but I can’t find it...

I would like to recommend installing the plugin and trying it, but it can be used only with a specific database… Has anyone ever faced this problem? Any fix for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `showAttributeTable` inside `postProcessAlgorithm` method. Also, add `self.` to `layer*` variables to be able to access them in `postProcessAlgorithm` method.

For example:

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    
    # other stuffs
    
    # Add 'self'
    self.layer_map = QgsVectorLayer(...)

    # Remove two following lines. You will add those to postProcessAlgorithm method
    # iface.showAttributeTable(layer_map)
    # iface.setActiveLayer(layer_map)    

    # other stuffs


def postProcessAlgorithm(self, context, feedback):

    lyr = QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString(self.layer_map, context)

    iface.showAttributeTable(lyr)
    iface.setActiveLayer(lyr)

    return {}
```

[image]